# Converting Parse to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I have read the posts creating the Parse environment on a MondoDB instance on AWS, but I am more interested in converting my parse storage to native AWS.  Does anyone have any examples of doing this.  I am trying to figure out if you can use S3 or do you have to use the noSql DB to mimic the "Class", "Column" structure of Parse.  My App uses the Class name as the customer and the columns are the customer specific data files, the columns are all text files and image files.  Thanks